# Create space between flex children and grandchildren

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following structure

```
<div class="parent" style="display: flex">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2" style="display: flex">
        <div class="grandchild1"></div>
        <div class="grandchild2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to create gutters ( margins ) between `.child1` and `.child2` and between `.grandchild1` and `.granchild2` ? Basically the final result should be 3 boxes next to each other with equal margins between them.

Comment: .child1 { margin-right : 20px} ?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to display the grandchildren like the empty children.
You can do this with the current markup with [display: contents](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#valdef-display-contents)

[Caniuse:](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they
>   were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element
>   itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored
>   when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}
.child2 {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="grandchild1">grandchild1</div>
    <div class="grandchild2">grandchild2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NB:** Currently `display: contents` isn't yet supported in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a css - margin (added common class "create-space")

```css
.create-space{
  margin-right : 20px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="display: flex">
    <div class="child1 create-space">child1</div>
    <div class="child2" style="display: flex">
        <div class="grandchild1 create-space">grandchild1</div>
        <div class="grandchild2 create-space">grandchild2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```